# Spring integration scatterGather usage

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

In my use case I need to make 2 REST calls to fetch a list of items based on departmentId. I need to merge the 2 lists and process them.

I am using the scatterGather pattern, i can see that the fetchRoles & fetchGroups are being called but i dont see "Aggregated List:" is printed at the end. Can some one help me what is wrong in the code

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow processDomainFileFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("receiverChannel")
            .scatterGather(scatterer -> scatterer
                            .applySequence(true)
                            .recipientFlow(fetchRoles())
                            .recipientFlow(fetchGroups()))
            .log(INFO, CATEGORY, m -> "Aggregated List: " + m.getPayload())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fetchRoles() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("fetch.roles")
            .handle(outboundGateway( someServiceUrl + "/{departmentId}/roles")
                    .uriVariable("departmentId", m -> m.getHeaders().get("departmentId"))
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(Item[].class))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fetchGroups() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("fetch.groups")
            .handle(outboundGateway(someServiceUrl + "/{departmentId}/groups")
                    .uriVariable("departmentId", m -> m.getHeaders().get("departmentId"))
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(Item[].class))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as you use a default correlation strategy in the `gatherer`, you are missing the

```
/**
 * @param applySequence the applySequence.
 * @return the router spec.
 * @see AbstractMessageRouter#setApplySequence(boolean)
 */
public S applySequence(boolean applySequence) {
```

on the `scatterer` to let it to populate a standard sequence details headers to let a default correlation logic to do its job based on the provided sequence details headers: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#scatter-gather-functionality

Comment: Also, this `.releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() > 0))` looks suspicious - it will release when only one message is in the group.

Comment: Yeah... That's good catch, indeed, but at the same time this is slightly different story...

Comment: It didn't work even after adding `.applySequence(true)`. I kept some debug stmts in releaseStrategy which are not executed. I thought the default releaseStrategy is on aggregate completion hence i mentioned group.size() > 0, only go to next step when the result is more than zero

Comment: Try to remove `gatherer` argument altogether from there. This way it is going to be based on the default aggregation strategy which comes from the `sequenceDetails` headers by the mentioned `.applySequence(true)`

Comment: I have a logger between `handle()` and `get()`  `.log(DEBUG, CATEGORY, m -> "Roles fetched: " + m.getPayload().size())`, when i comment the logger then only it worked. Not sure how logger is affecting the flow

Comment: `log()` in the end of the flow is terminal operator. No reply is going to sent after that

Comment: I have to write this `.<List<Item[]>>handle((p, h) -> p.stream().flatMap(m -> Arrays.asList(m).stream()).collect((Collectors.toList())))` in order to merge the 2 responses.